# 2d Multimedia Library on the JVM

Tags: java, scala, jvm, 2d, hardware-acceleration

I'm searching for a rich 2d multimedia framework that's meant to be used with the JVM

- There's SDL and SFML for C and C++.
- I've used Pygame with Python. It's very productive.
- XNA is great, too.

What about the JVM ? I know that there's a wrapper around SDL http://sdljava.sourceforge.net/ but since the last entry on the homepages newsfeed dates back to 2005 it doesn't feel particularly alive.

**Basically what I'm looking for is a hardware accelerated 2d canvas for the JVM that is backed with a neat framework.**

I know that C, C++ and even Python (to some extent) can be considered low-level languages. Java on the other hand abstracts over the hardware. Therefore what I'm searching for is not it's "natural territory". Nevertheless http://lwjgl.org/ is a great example of what is possible in Java.

Googling brought up this interesting project http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ . Have you used it ? Do you know alternatives ? Please note: I'd like to use Scala, not Java. Therefore the stress on JVM and not just Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already looked at [JavaFX 2.0](http://javafx.com/about-javafx/)?

Rendering engine is based on prism, which supports hardware and software rendering (this means it will use either DirectX or OpenGL or Java 2D depending on what's available). You can find more information about it's architecture here:

[JavaFX Architecture and Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm)

It uses Scene Graph in order to define things you want to render. Here you can find small introduction:

[Working with the JavaFX Scene Graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/scenegraph/jfxpub-scenegraph.htm)

[Scalafx project](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/) provides Scala bindings for JavaFX 2.0.

Comment: JavaFX 2 is definitely a good way to go, but at the moment ScalaFX is nowhere near complete or usable. You can of course still use JavaFX from Scala because it's just a library, but your code will look very similar to how it would in Java. Check out some of the demos on YouTube - they're quite impressive.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: Yes, you are right, it's not finished yet. But future looks promising: http://javafx.com/roadmap/ . It's also nice, that they are planing to include JavaFX 3.0 in JDK 8.

Comment: it took me some time to work through the tutorial. JavaFX is indeed impressive. I'll use it for  now and jump to ScalaFX as soon as it seems stable

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that works use http://lwjgl.org/ from scala.